# Switch from Keyboard to Touchscreen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can i switch this "movement"(Horizontal RotateAround movement with keyboard) in Update to an Android platform, I mean touchable movement(working on touchscreen).

I tried to put instead of "Horizontal" the "Mouse X" or "Mouse Y" it works with mouse and touchscreen to, but just in a wrong way. I know it's wrong and unplayable like this.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed = 350f;

    float movement = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        //movement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
        //movement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.forward, movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime * -moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Adding Mobile Controls  Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/adding-mobile-controls)

Comment: This Tutorial is for iOS and did not answered my question already...

Comment: @SoosIstvan Where did you see that the tutorial was for iOS? Unity handles the same way the touch controls for **every touch** device, no matter the OS.... Without mentionning that it does not seem you have put much effort into trying the suggested solution.

Comment: Did you take a look at [`Touch.deltaPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaPosition.html)? `if( Input.touchCount > 0 ) movement = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x;`

Comment: Now it is working. Thank you. <3 . Just one more question .. If i can slower my Player move speed somehow, because the "public float moveSpeed = ...f" doesn't affect the swiping/touching speed... :/

Comment: `transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.forward, movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime * -moveSpeed);` since you multiply `movement` by `moveSpeed`, I believe changing the value of the latter should influence the rotation speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to undestand that touchscreen is not one thing.
You can decide to use the screen, a virtual joystick, a button or something else.
Input.GetAxis and GetAxisRaw just tell Unity to use what you have in the Input default system settings and use that as an input.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html

So, for example when you use Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") if you have set in your Unity Input settings W as positive and S as negative input, Unity will use your keyboard and an equivalent to Input.GetKeyDown and get the value of W when is pressed. Since the keyboard value is always 1 or 0 it will be the same to use GetAxis or GetAxisRaw (since GetAxisRaw always get 1 or 0 but with the keyboad you will always get 1 or 0)... a real joystick will get a value from -1 to 1 with 0 as "not using the joystick" 1 as max positive value and -1 as max negative value.

To replace the keyboard kind of behaviour you can, for example, create 2 buttons with Unity UI system and if they are pressed (there are many default way to tell if a UI Button is pressed, for example the OnButtonDown method) you will set a float value to 1f, 0f if ButtonUp... that way you will be able to get 0f or 1f like with the default Input system, you will get a positive 1f value from the virtual button instead of getting a positive input value from the W button.

If you want a value from 0f to 1f (like 0.4) you will need a virtual joystick or something like that.
You can use this short tutorial to make one:
https://youtu.be/uSnZuBhOA2U

The main thing to understand is that you cannot use the default Input system for touchscreen so you should create that system from scratch, then you will be able to use it like the default Input system (just with a different class that you need to decide).